# Data rendering on html table using Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using following script for angular. I am able to print `console.log(  $scope.categorylisting);`
in following format

```
[{"_id":"56910a45889f853c14f59092","tagname":"man","slug":"man","__v":0,"count":0,"parent":"0","description":null},{"_id":"569342c9a0f3720c13e4d1d1","tagname":"women","slug":"women","__v":0,"count":0,"parent":"0","description":null}]
```

from following code but can not get value in html. Any help would be appreciated!

```
var app = angular.module('forsubmitApp',  []);
app.controller('adminFormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

 var formdata = {
      tagname: "default",
      slug: "default",
      parent: "0", 
   };


 $scope.adminSubmitForm = function() {
  console.log($scope.formdata);
   $http({

   url: "/admin/addcategory",
   data:  $.param($scope.formdata),
   method: 'POST',

   headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

  }).success(function(data){
   $scope.formdata={};
   alert("Category Added Successfully")

   }).error(function(err){"ERR", console.log(err)})
   };

    });
    var catarray =[];
    app.controller('adminListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     // function adminListCtrl($scope, $http) {

    var loadCategoryList = function(){
    $http({
       method: 'GET',
         url: '/admin/fetchcategorylist',
       headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

   }).success(function(data, status) {

       catarray.push(angular.toJson(data,false));
       $scope.categorylisting= angular.toJson(data);
         console.log(  $scope.categorylisting);
     });

     };
  loadCategoryList();
  });
```

My target http call in node controller using mongodb.

```
  app.get('/admin/fetchcategorylist',function(req,res){
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.setHeader('charset', 'utf-8');
     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');  
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  Category.find({parent:"0"},function(err,docs){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(docs));
   res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));
  })
  });
```

Following is the html part for same.

```
  <div class="mainpanel"  ng-app="forsubmitApp" >
  <div id="col-right"  n>

  <table ng-controller="adminListCtrl" class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped tags ui-sortable"  >
  <thead>
   <tr>

    <th scope="col" id="slug" class="manage-column column-slug sortable desc"><a href="#"><span>Slug</span><span class="sorting-indicator"></span></a></th>

    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:tag" >

   <tr id="tag-37" class="ui-sortable-handle"  ng-repeat="category in categorylisting track by $index ">

    <td class="slug column-slug" data-colname="Slug" style="cursor: move;">{{category.slug}}</td>

   </tr>
   </tbody>

   </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you are adding binding expression "{{categorylisting}}" to '' tag directly. I think this is not the correct position to write binding expression.

Please try removing "{{categorylisting}}" from '' tag, as binding expression  should't be used at this position.

Comment: I don't think that causes any problem. I was just checking either data is rendering or not!!! I have edited that.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is with the usage of `angular.toJson()`.
 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

`angular.toJson()` serializes an object or an array into a single string.  This string is great for passing to a server, but it is no longer an object and can't be iterated through.

In your case, the data coming from the server should be usable as is without any kind of serialization, i.e. `$scope.categorylisting=data`.

If you do indeed need to deserialize the information coming from the server for some reason (this shouldn't be necessary since `$http` does it automatically), you would use `angular.fromJson()` instead.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

Incidentally, you should consider whenever possible using `.then()` rather than the deprecated `.success()`.

When using `.then()`, the callback function is slightly different. The `.then()` callback receives additional information about the response from the server.  The following code is the correct format for `.then()`:

```js
.then(function(response) {
  catarray.push(response.data);
  $scope.categorylisting = response.data;
  console.log($scope.categorylisting);
});
```

Comment: getting http call : Object {data: Array[2], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
config: Object
data: Array[2]
0: Object
1: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
headers: (c)
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
modified code:
var loadCategoryList = function(){
        $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: '/admin/fetchcategorylist',
           headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}      }).then(function(data, status) {     
           $scope.categorylisting=data;
            
       });
   };

Comment: using `.then()`, the syntax is different.  `.then()` returns an object with status messages and text from the server, where `.success()` did not.  I'll update the question with the correct format when using `.then()`.

Comment: Now i got this output
[Object, Object]
in this i have data but still it is not rendering.
 var loadCategoryList = function(){
        $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: '/admin/fetchcategorylist',
           headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

       }).then(function(response) {
         console.log(response.data);
           
           $scope.categorylisting=response.data;
             console.log(  $scope.categorylisting);
       });

   };

Comment: does each one of those objects have the data you expect when you expand them in the console?  if the data is indeed being returned from the server in the format you posted in the beginning of the question, the HTML should be working.

Comment: Yes, It is, 
app.get('/admin/fetchcategorylist',function(req,res){
     res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       res.setHeader('charset', 'utf-8');
         res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');  
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');   
     Category.find({parent:"0"},function(err,docs){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(docs));
       res.send(JSON.stringify(docs));
     })
});
This is the target http call from where i am getting same json data as i posted in beginning.

Comment: I recreated the code in a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jzORKPp7mwuNJY3XCCd8?p=preview.  I hardcoded the response from the server rather than using the `$http`, but you should be able to compare the console.log of the version I wrote against the console.log you are getting to see if there are any differences.  As you can see, however, the HTML works without any modification.

Comment: I guess my http call is happening after my view rendering so ,it is not assigning value in $scope.categorylisting. i am using node js as interface with mongo db . So i guess $scope getting value late through angular js .I have tried your staitic data ,without http , same thing happening no data is being display in html.Suggest please

Comment: it wasn't *my* static data, it was a direct copy from your question, as was the HTML.  how is your environment different from what you posted?

Comment: I have edited my initial question , I am using node+mongo and for front end in some cases i want to use angular like listing , searching etc. I am getting no error when i am running my updated code as you said i have matched , everything is in right place, but still nothing is being render in table . Its weird for me too. I have two row in data as you can see, these two row is there as table row in my view but blank , no data is showing up, that means ng-repeat having right data objects having two records , but data is not showing.